# What is the name of a decision algorithm answering 'yes' or 'maybe'?

Tags: algorithm, naming

I am wondering what the name of a decision algorithm is that does *not* return 'yes' or 'no', but can only decide 'yes' for a real subset of inputs and can not provide a definitive decision for the rest.

A suitable example would be an algorithm for deciding invertibility of a matrix - my algorithm correctly answers 'yes' for a subclass of matrices, but can neither confirm nor deny it for the rest.

In my mind, this is (kind of) a sound under-approximation of the real answer, but Wikipedia defines an approximation algorithm only within the realms of optimization.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: "Incomplete"?

Btw, matrix invertibility is "decidable", so algorithms that can decide on that totally exist ;)

Comment: This question might be better suited for [cs.SE] than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Lagerbaer (I think) that OP is more concerned with the actual algorithm's terminology than the problem. Decidable, semidecidable, etc. etc. are all fine for problem classification.

Comment: The example with matrices is not the point here ;)
Also: For matrices over arbitrary structures the complexity might make me prefer the "incomplete" algorithm, if it answers yes for my relevant subclass.

Yes, its about the Terminology.

Comment: Kind of indecisive classification.

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD, do you have a German name for such algorithm?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz No, I am much more familiar with CS in the english language :/

Comment: "Probabilistic algorithm"? However this might be different, this classification of algorithms tend to produce "maybe" or "no" rather than "maybe" or "yes"

Comment: I'd still go with "incomplete", because there's a subset of inputs for which the algorithm provides no answer.

Comment: Maybe the word you are looking for is an algorithm which produced a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) answer?

Comment: sounds like some kind of **fuzzy logic** or if you are looking for  stochastic then google **Monte Carlo** methods

Answer (score 1):

You may be referring to randomized / probabilistic algorithms or randomized data structures.

Algorithms that probabilistically determine if a number is prime or not (a [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)) are examples of such randomized algorithms. The Miller-Rabin algorithm is a concrete example.

Data structures can be built to use probability for some operations. A [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is one such probabilistic data structure.

Comment: No, there is no probabilistic aspect to this algorithm - for some input i the result of the algorithm is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Las-Vegas algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm) are something very similar: If a Las-Vegas algorithm terminates, the result is correct. If it doesn't - it is your "maybe".

Actually in real life those algorithms will be interrupted after some time without result.